# Subtract Set Value at Aggregated Level

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Values are for two groups by quarter.

In DAX, need to summarize all the data but also need to remove -5 from each quarter (-20 for full year) in 2021 for Group 1, without allowing the value to go below 0.

**This only impacts:**

- Group 1
- 2021

However, **I also need to retain the data details without the adjustment.** So I can't do this in Power Query.

**Data:**

| Group | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 10 |
| 1 | 02/01/2020 | 9 |
| 1 | 03/01/2020 | 10 |
| 1 | 04/01/2020 | 8 |
| 1 | 05/01/2020 | 10 |
| 1 | 06/01/2020 | 11 |
| 1 | 07/01/2020 | 18 |
| 1 | 08/01/2020 | 2 |
| 1 | 09/01/2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 10/01/2020 | 0 |
| 1 | 11/01/2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 12/01/2020 | 0 |
| 1 | 01/01/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 02/01/2021 | 12 |
| 1 | 03/01/2021 | 12 |
| 1 | 04/01/2021 | 3 |
| 1 | 05/01/2021 | 13 |
| 1 | 06/01/2021 | 14 |
| 1 | 07/01/2021 | 7 |
| 1 | 08/01/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 09/01/2021 | 0 |
| 1 | 10/01/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 11/01/2021 | 2 |
| 1 | 12/01/2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 | 18 |
| 2 | 02/01/2020 | 7 |
| 2 | 03/01/2020 | 6 |
| 2 | 04/01/2020 | 8 |
| 2 | 05/01/2020 | 12 |
| 2 | 06/01/2020 | 13 |
| 2 | 07/01/2020 | 14 |
| 2 | 08/01/2020 | 8 |
| 2 | 09/01/2020 | 7 |
| 2 | 10/01/2020 | 6 |
| 2 | 11/01/2020 | 5 |
| 2 | 12/01/2020 | 4 |
| 2 | 01/01/2021 | 12 |
| 2 | 02/01/2021 | 18 |
| 2 | 03/01/2021 | 19 |
| 2 | 04/01/2021 | 20 |
| 2 | 05/01/2021 | 12 |
| 2 | 06/01/2021 | 12 |
| 2 | 07/01/2021 | 7 |
| 2 | 08/01/2021 | 18 |
| 2 | 09/01/2021 | 16 |
| 2 | 10/01/2021 | 15 |
| 2 | 11/01/2021 | 13 |
| 2 | 12/01/2021 | 1 |

**Result:**

| Qtr/Year | Group 1 Value | Group 2 Value | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q1-2020 | 29 | 31 | 60 |
| Q2-2020 | 29 | 33 | 62 |
| Q3-2020 | 21 | 29 | 50 |
| Q4-2020 | 1 | 15 | 16 |
| **2020** | **80** | **108** | **188** |
| Q1-2021 | 20 | 49 | 69 |
| Q2-2021 | 25 | 44 | 69 |
| Q3-2021 | 3 | 41 | 44 |
| Q4-2021 | **0** | 29 | 29 |
| **2021** | **48** | **271** | **211** |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest summarizing at the Year/Quarter/Group granularity and summing that up as follows:

```
SumValue = 
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table2,
        Table2[Year],
        Table2[Qtr],
        Table2[Group],
        "@RawValue", SUM ( Table2[Value] ),
        "@RemoveValue", IF ( Table2[Year] = 2021 && Table2[Group] = 1, 5 )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( Summary, MAX ( [@RawValue] - [@RemoveValue], 0 ) )
```

(This assumes the amount to remove for a year is the same as for four quarters.)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi, I need to subtract a set value of -3 per quarter (-12) in 2021 for group 1 only. Not subtract out rows.

Comment: That's what this does though because there are three months per quarter and twelve months per year.

Comment: -3 and -12 need to be explicit, sorry I realize the confusion. The numbers weren't meant to be related to months in a quarter/year. I changed the example to -5 for each quarter for the full year (-20) of 2021 for group 1 only.